# Importing an array from CSV to Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple CSV file with two fields. One is a string and the other is an array being the elements of the name.

"John Citizen", "[John, Citizen]"

When I import this into Firestore the second field is stored as a string and not parsed as an array.

How can I import these fields as String and Array?

```
    db.collection('people').add({
        name: record.name,
        elements: record.elements
    })
    .then(function(docRef) {
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
```

Comment: Firestore doesn't parse any of its inputs.  You will have to write code to further parse the second field, and create an an array variable to pass to Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, I fixed it by converting my "array" to a string (CSV) and then converting it back to an array. I don't know why but my Angular UI code was converting it back to a string when I tried to push the value to Firestore.

Solution:

```js
record.elements = this.elementsStringToArray(record.elements.toString());

private elementsStringToArray(elementsString: String): String[] {
  const elementsArray = elementsString.slice(0, elementsString.length).split(',');
  return elementsArray;
}
```